# Execute php script before every php script?

Tags: php

How would I run this before every php script besides putting it in all of them?

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '123.123.123.123')
{
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'];
}
```

I basically want the same affect as putting that at the top of every script without actually doing that.

Comment: Be aware that the `HTTP_X_REAL_IP` header can be easily forged by the client, while that's not so easy for `REMOTE_ADDR`.

Comment: Don't you have a single point of entry for your application?

Comment: That is why the 'if' is there. The address it checks for is my proxy servers ip.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put it in its own file and set the `auto_prepend_file` configuration in the php.ini / .htaccess file to point to it.

Update: Since you mentioned lighttpd in a comment, note that you can configure it like this in the global INI file with PHP 5.3:

```
[PATH=/vhost/domain.com]  
auto_prepend_file = /vhost/domain.com/foo.php

[HOST=domain.com]
auto_prepend_file = /vhost/domain.com/foo.php
```

Or you can create the file `/vhost/domain.com/.user.ini` and do the same:

```
auto_prepend_file = /vhost/domain.com/foo.php
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792069/how-to-include-a-php-file-site-wide-using-htaccess-or-other-methods/3792076#3792076

Comment: +1 for lighttpd example. I'm tempted to add "lighthttpd" to the question title for future generations

Answer (score 2):

If you have the necessary rights to change your PHP configuration, [`auto_prepend_file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) is exactly what you're looking for.

> `auto_prepend_file`
>   Specifies the name of a file that is automatically parsed before the main file. The file is included as if it was called with the require() function, so include_path is used.
>
> The special value `none` disables auto-prepending.

Comment: Thanks, just curious would there be a nicer way to do it for lighttpd just for 1 virtual host?

Comment: PHP 5.3 supports `.user.ini` files per directory when running via CGI.

Comment: @High I don't know lighthttpd well enough but you may be able to set the option in a `.htaccess` file

Comment: lighttpd doesn't use/support .htaccess. .user.ini is the way to go.