# Embed a PHP file into INI

Tags: php, include, ini

I'd like to insert a line, similar to include('path to php file.php'), into php.ini.
Actually I already found this solution from the Internet, however I don't remember which parameter is used in php.ini in this case.

For what: I want to execute a short code (written by php) before every php script from my web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking to run a PHP script before all files on your server? If so, the [auto-prepend-file](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) directive in [php.ini configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) is perfect for this. From the help docs:

> Specifies the name of a file that is automatically parsed before the
> main file. The file is included as if it was called with the require
> function, so include_path is used.
>
> The special value none disables auto-prepending.

Sample Code:

```
# Inside either main php.ini or child file
auto_prepend_file=/path/to/your/global/php/file.php
```

Note that PHP also gives the ability to **append** a file after every script interpretation as well. There is also a [previous SO entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841526/execute-php-script-before-every-php-script) for this with additional information. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

You must be searching for [auto_prepend_file](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) or [auto_append_file](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-append-file), i.e.:

`auto_prepend_file` string

> Specifies the name of a file that is automatically parsed **before** the
>   main file. The file is included as if it was called with the require
>   function, so `include_path` is used.

`auto_append_file` string

> Specifies the name of a file that is automatically parsed **after** the
>   main file. The file is included as if it was called with the require
>   function, so `include_path` is used.

---

Usage `php.ini`:

```
auto_prepend_file="/path/to/prepend.php"
auto_append_file="/path/to/append.php"
```