# $_SESSION['nonce'] - where did it come from?

Tags: php, session

As I am setting my own session variables, I suddenly find (`var_dump($_SESSION)`) that my `$_SESSION` array has a variable called `nonce` in it. I'm not setting it( knowingly ). Any ideas as to what sets variable `nonce` into my `$_SESSION` array?

Could it be a dependency or a session config setting?

I set `booktitle`, not `nonce`. This is part of the `var_dump` result:

```
array(6) {
  ["nonce"]=>
  string(128) "5914056215a1efb5369e7b2fd14739c666d5dd1c17bd0312c5b5d196afdf0400ee78aac4e70d16bc6f23bc216086a45a1315ce21fbb8ad8ad85b4432a661ba0e"
  ["booktitle"]=>
  string(5) "jimmy"
```

Code of session configuration:

```
$this->session = [
            'cookie_httponly' => true, // XSS
            'strict_mode' => true, // session fixation
            'use_cookies' => true,
            'use_only_cookies' => true,
            'cookie_secure' => $secure, // HTTPS only
            'cookie_domain' => '/',
            'cookie_lifetime' => 0, // untill browser closed
            'use_trans_sid' => false
        ];
```

Then on each page: `session_start();` and setting variables:

```
$_SESSION['booktitle'] = 'jimmy';
```

PHP/Framework/OS:

PHP 7.1.3
No framework, only 1 dependency Flintstone( key-value flat file database )
OS Windows 10( v 1709 ).

`phpinfo()`: Session:

```
Session Support     enabled
Registered save handlers    files user
Registered serializer handlers  php_serialize php php_binary wddx
Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.cache_expire    180 180
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.gc_divisor  1000    1000
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.lazy_write  On  On
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   no value    no value
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.sid_bits_per_character  5   5
session.sid_length  26  26
session.upload_progress.cleanup On  On
session.upload_progress.enabled On  On
session.upload_progress.freq    1%  1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq    1   1
session.upload_progress.name    PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix  upload_progress_    upload_progress_
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    On  On
session.use_strict_mode Off Off
session.use_trans_sid   0   0
```

Comment: no idea; post your code.

Comment: which framework and version of php are you using and on what OS? what does `phpinfo()` show in regards to sessions/cookies?

Comment: maybe I should ask the duck...

Comment: *heh,* yeah maybe you should ;-) careful though, he seems to be quite the quack!

Comment: You need to search your project for "nonce", as it may be being set in a way other than `$_SESSION['nonce'] = `. Also check your HTML forms (eg login form most likely culprit), and wherever you set your cookies.

Comment: @James, I did try 'nonce' as well, but no luck, I'm still at a loss. I'm going to delve into the plugins and server side scripts that Martin mentioned, last resort.

Answer (score 0):

You need to search your entire project codebase for "`$_SESSION['nonce']`" to see what is writing (or reading) this value. This is easily done in almost all IDEs.

If nothing is found then it might be some sort of plugin you're using typically for a data submit form (`<form>`) or communications interface.

Something somewhere is writing:

```
$_SESSION['nonce'] = blahblah;
```

But we can't tell you where this is happening as it's specific to your code and is not a "general" characteristic.

## UPDATE:

> Searched the project but no hits. At least I can rule-out any 'general' (e.g. ini setting) as the culprit - thanks anyway

Then you need to find out about plugins and server side scripts which can be added to all files by the php.ini, such as `auto_prepend_file` as [outlined in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841526/execute-php-script-before-every-php-script).

Comment: Searched the project but no hits. At least I can rule-out any 'general' (e.g. ini setting) as the culprit - thanks anyway

Comment: @jibsteroos please read my updated answer. If it's not that; then I don't know what else it may be without exploring your server for myself.