# workaround for $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] with loadbalancer

Tags: php, apache

I have a legacy PHP application that use a lot of $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']

I am migrating from a keepalived loadbalancer (Direct Server Return) to an AWS ELB.

this means that the real client IP that was in $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] is now in $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']

Is there a way to avoid replacing all the PHP code from REMOTE_ADDR to HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR ?
I have almost 300 occurences...

I know it would be a crap workaround. like tweaking apache or php config ?

Comment: You could do something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841526/execute-php-script-before-every-php-script

Comment: Not sure if there is something I'm missing here. But... How about opening the entire project in vscode or your favorite editor of choice and simply replace all $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] with $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']? You'll be done less than a minute and even have time to brew yourself a fresh coffee :-)

Comment: @Christian I will try the big sed anyway but I simplified a bit and the app do nasty manipulations with $_SERVER array. so I'm a bit terrified and want to consider all the possibilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Apache2, you can do that easily and transparently:

Enable remoteip:

```
sudo a2enmod remoteip 
sudo a2enconf remoteip
```

Edit remoteip config:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/conf-available/remoteip.conf
```

With a content similar to this (change source IP for your load-balancer):

```
# Trust X-Forwarded-For headers from the OVHcloud Load Balancer
# See https://www.ovh.com/manager/sunrise/iplb/index.html#/iplb for an up to date list
RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
RemoteIPInternalProxy <source_nat_ip>
```

If you want apache log to use actual client IP, you need those in one of apache.conf files:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%v %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" vhost_common
```

Restart Apache and from now on PHP receives actual client source IP instead of load balancer.

Comment: That looks really useful. It's probably worth linking to the [documentation for that Apache module](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_remoteip.html) for people who need to use it with other OSes (`a2enmod` is a Debian/Ubuntu script, not part of Apache itself) or who want more detail of the available options.

Comment: The `LogFormat` lines look like they're just the standard definitions, and don't have anything specific to do with the rest of the answer. The [list of formats](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats) says that `%h` and `%a` will just automatically use the "real" IP address once the rest of the config is in place, so you only need to do something different if you want to log the actual load-balancer address, which would be `%{c}h` instead of `%h` (or `%{c}a` instead of `%a`).

Comment: that's what I also found finally (and forgot to answer my own question)