# How include a PHP file in all other PHP file of a site?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hi I have to include a PHP file in all other PHP file of my site.

This is a sample of my sitemap:

```
|index.php
|foolder1
||    file1.php
||    check.php
|foolder2
||    file2.php
|foolder3
||    file3.php
```

I want that all PHP file have included `check.php`, I must say that I can't edit `php.ini` and I know there is `php_value auto_prepend_file "check.php"` but I don't know how this function run then I'm asking help to use `php_value auto_prepend_file` or another way to include my file in all other PHP file? Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

I know that in StakOverflow there are some question like this but i can't edit php.ini (some server restrictions...) and I've just try to put `php_value auto_prepend_file "foolder1/check.php"` in `.htaccess` and it run for `index.php` but not for `file1.php`, `file2.php`,...

Comment: Why not just add that `<?php include "check.php" ?>` at the beginning of each file? It's only 29 characters...

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792069/how-to-include-a-php-file-site-wide-using-htaccess-or-other-methods) -------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

Comment: Because I have like 120 php file then i can't add this code in all single file and i create a new file everyday.

Comment: Yes in stackoverflow there are some question like this but there isn't any good answer that explain me how to do it.

Comment: You've not read the answer FirstOne linked, then. That link has the answer to your question

Comment: Read the related article FirstOne posted

Comment: in this link there is 4 answer that say the same thing: "use php_value auto_prepend_file "check.php" " but i said that I can't edit PHP.ini and I don't know where to write or how to use 'php_value auto_prepend_file "check.php"'

Comment: Sorry but the answers DO say that _They can be changed via .htaccess_. And what is `.htaccess` but your chosen tag?

Comment: I know that there is this function but I don't know how to use it because when I do some test if I use php_value auto_prepend_file "foolder1/check.php" when i go in foolder1/file1.php it can't find "foolder1" inside "foolder1"!! but if i use php_value auto_prepend_file "../foolder1/check.php index.php can't find "../foolder1"

Answer (score 1):

A better way might be to use what is called the front controller pattern.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # Explicitly disable rewriting for front controllers
    RewriteRule ^app_dev.php - [L]
    RewriteRule ^app.php - [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

You would get your web server to pass all requests into `app.php` and then you bootstrap the application and then pass the request on to the relevant scripts.

```
// app.php
//
// Do shared steps like setup the database

switch($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) {
  case "foo/bar":
    require "foo/bar.php";
    break;
  case "baz/woo":
    require "baz/woo.php";
    break;
  default:
    require "404.php";
}
```

The main advantage here is that you are abstracting your URL:s from the actual file structure and also removing the server technology from your URLs which is a good practice.

Comment: Since your existing setup exposes filenames of the PHP files you would potentially be able to passthrough using the rewrite and replace the switch statement (of hard coded require's) with a simple router.  Be careful to validate the filename though so its bound to a known directory and ensures the file exists etc.

Comment: This is just a basic example - creating all the routes in your application in a switch statement is not really a good router. You might want to look into the front controller pattern and the [symfony routing component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/introduction.html) to get a better understanding.

Comment: @JackSkinner I deliberately hardcoded it. Taking `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and using it to directly load a file is a really bad practice as it can allow a malicious user to execute scripts that are not intended to be run. Securing a dynamic file based router is extremely hard.

Comment: 100% agree, thus the suggestion of validation etc.  Done correctly its faster than a switch and in no worse a position than the existing situation.

Answer (score 0):

i am assuming you are using apache2.

Lets say on Ubuntu 14.04

Edit

```
etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

add below line inside the **VirtualHost**

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "/var/www/html/check.php"
```

restart apache server.  **i tested this and its working**

Edit:
i tried with .htaccess, which is also working for me.

please note 2 things

1) .htaccess is enabled
[How to enable use of .htaccess in Apache on Ubuntu](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61009/how-to-enable-use-of-htaccess-in-apache-on-ubuntu)

2) provide absolute path for check.php

anyhow both worked for me