# Execute on every PHP request

Tags: php

I am using IIS 8 and PHP 7 with no additional frameworks.

Is there hook in PHP where I could execute some PHP code before or after a PHP file is being processed? 
Or maybe before or after a request is being made?

I basically want to unset a session variable after the user clicks somewhere else (requests a different PHP file) or 5 minutes has passed.

Comment: Only think I can think of that might work: Is rewrite rules. Rewrite the requests to a PHP file, and then pass them to their intended destinations. AFAIK, no hooks

Comment: Look into `auto_prepend_file` php.ini directive.

Comment: Frameworks usually tackle this by sending all requests through a central index page via a rewrite which acts as a bootstrapper to initialise, pre-process, handle and then post-process the request.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `auto_prepend_file` and `auto_append_file` settings in `php.ini`

Check those questions:

[How To Include a PHP File Site-wide Using .HTACCESS or other methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792069/how-to-include-a-php-file-site-wide-using-htaccess-or-other-methods/3792076#3792076)

[Execute php script before every php script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841526/execute-php-script-before-every-php-script)

PS. Also rethink your idea. Does not sound right.